# Min value in Haskell excluding 0

Tags: haskell, minimum

im passing a list of tuples eg [(45.4, [9.0]), (0, [9.1])] into a function that will get the smallest

here is the code i have so far

```
minr :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a 
minr [] = error "List is empty"
minr [x] = x  
minr (x:y:xs) = if x < y then 
                   if x > 0 then minr(x:xs) 
                   else minr(y:xs)
               else minr(y:xs)
```

i can use the function without the if x > 0 then the function will work correctly but when i try to compare it using > 0 then it doesnt work.

fix i removed the 0 before comparing and i know that the compare wasnt working due to the type declaration thanks for the help

Comment: What kind of errors? [No errors here](http://ideone.com/Gcg35g)

Comment: could not deduce (Num a) arising from the literal '0'

Comment: found answer 
newlist = filter condition test
     where condition (n,_) = n > 0

Comment: Remove the type signature. Then type `:t minr` in ghci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your list is a list of `a` which is generic (and not a number), Haskell can't let you just compare it to 0...
You can try setting `(Num a, Ord a)` as a constraint.

Your current code doesn't deal with tuples at all by the way, but I'll let you solve that one yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the tuple part, as your sample was operating on arrays, but here is an option:

```
 foldl (\a x -> if x==0 then a else min x a)  (maxBound :: Int) [9,15,12,0,5,6,7,8,9]
```

The result is 5.
For empty arrays it gives back maxBound which is a quite huge number.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the most efficient way, but simple enough. First filter out zero values. Then sort the remaining in ascending order, and take the first (`head`).

For empty lists, including the case of a list with all zero values, `head` will err. This is well-defined up to the question statement / requirements.

Thus consider,

```
import Data.List

minr :: (Ord a, Num a) => [(a,[a])] -> (a,[a])
minr = head . sort . filter (\(y,_) -> y /= 0)
```

and so

```
λ> minr [(45.4, [9.0]), (0, [9.1]), (7,[1.2])]
(7.0,[1.2])
```

However

```
λ> minr []
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list

λ> minr [(0.0, [9.0]), (0, [9.1]), (0,[1.2])]
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the answer i got, might not be good but it works

```
newlist = filter condition tuplename
 where condition (n,_) = n > 0
```

Comment: This doesn't do exactly the same thing as the other version.